# Why do my stage-2 and stage-3 differ after GCC bootstrap

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, build, compiler-optimization

I have recently got into building gcc on my own from official git repository. I am using Arch Linux with all necessary libraries installed from official repositories. I have done the following:

1. Cloned gcc source from git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
2. Checked out tag releases/gcc-12.2.0
3. Made separate directory outside gcc sourcetree
4. Ran ../gcc/configure without any additional arguments
5. Ran make -j8 (just to speed up the process)

After these steps, the build process finished just fine without any errors during the comparison. Stage 2 and 3 appeared to be identical. However, when I repeated the process, this time with:

5. make BOOT_CFLAGS='-march=native -O3 -flto=auto'

Resulting stages 2 and 3 differ drastically in sizes (with stage-3 objects being usually 2 times smaller from stage-2) and thus comparison step fails. The exact output being:

```
make "DESTDIR=" "RPATH_ENVVAR=LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "TARGET_SUBDIR=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" "bindir=/usr/local/bin" "datadir=/usr/local/share" "exec_prefix=/usr/local" "includedir=/usr/local/include" "datarootdir=/usr/local/share" "docdir=/usr/local/share/doc/" "infodir=/usr/local/share/info" "pdfdir=/usr/local/share/doc/" "htmldir=/usr/local/share/doc/" "libdir=/usr/local/lib" "libexecdir=/usr/local/libexec" "lispdir=" "localstatedir=/usr/local/var" "mandir=/usr/local/share/man" "oldincludedir=/usr/include" "prefix=/usr/local" "sbindir=/usr/local/sbin" "sharedstatedir=/usr/local/com" "sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc" "tooldir=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" "build_tooldir=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" "target_alias=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" "AWK=gawk" "BISON=bison" "CC_FOR_BUILD=gcc" "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-g -O2" "CXX_FOR_BUILD=g++ -std=c++11" "EXPECT=expect" "FLEX=flex" "INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" "INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -c" "LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=" "LEX=flex" "M4=m4" "MAKE=make" "RUNTEST=runtest" "RUNTESTFLAGS=" "SED=/usr/bin/sed" "SHELL=/bin/sh" "YACC=bison -y" "`echo 'ADAFLAGS=' | sed -e s'/[^=][^=]*=$/XFOO=/'`" "ADA_CFLAGS=" "AR_FLAGS=rc" "echo 'BOOT_ADAFLAGS=-gnatpg' | sed -e s'/[^=][^=]*=$/XFOO=/'" "BOOT_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto" "BOOT_LDFLAGS=" "CFLAGS=-g -O2    " "CXXFLAGS=-g -O2    " "LDFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS=-g -O2  " "LIBCXXFLAGS=-g -O2   -fno-implicit-templates" "STAGE1_CHECKING=--enable-checking=yes,types" "STAGE1_LANGUAGES=c,c++,lto" "GNATBIND=gnatbind" "GNATMAKE=gnatmake" "GDC=gdc" "GDCFLAGS=-g -O2  " "AR_FOR_TARGET=ar" "AS_FOR_TARGET=as" "CC_FOR_TARGET=/home/urquelle/git/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/urquelle/git/build/./gcc/" "CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2" "CPPFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE" "DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=dlltool" "DSYMUTIL_FOR_TARGET=dsymutil" "FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include" "GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=/home/urquelle/git/build/./gcc/gfortran -B/home/urquelle/git/build/./gcc/" "GOC_FOR_TARGET=" "GOCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g" "GDC_FOR_TARGET=gdc" "GDCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g" "LD_FOR_TARGET=ld" "LIPO_FOR_TARGET=lipo" "LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2" "LIBCXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-implicit-templates" "NM_FOR_TARGET=nm" "OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=objdump" "OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=" "RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=ranlib" "READELF_FOR_TARGET=readelf" "STRIP_FOR_TARGET=strip" "WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=windres" "WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=windmc" "BUILD_CONFIG=bootstrap-debug" "echo 'LANGUAGES=' | sed -e s'/[^=][^=]*=$/XFOO=/'" "LEAN=false" "STAGE1_CFLAGS=-g" "STAGE1_CXXFLAGS=-g" "STAGE1_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGE1_TFLAGS=-fno-checking" "STAGE2_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fno-checking -gtoggle" "STAGE2_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fno-checking -gtoggle" "STAGE2_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGE2_TFLAGS=-fno-checking" "STAGE3_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fchecking=1" "STAGE3_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fchecking=1" "STAGE3_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGE3_TFLAGS=-fchecking=1" "STAGE4_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto" "STAGE4_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto" "STAGE4_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGE4_TFLAGS=" "STAGEprofile_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fno-checking -gtoggle -fprofile-generate" "STAGEprofile_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fno-checking -gtoggle -fprofile-generate" "STAGEprofile_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGEprofile_TFLAGS=-fno-checking" "STAGEtrain_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto" "STAGEtrain_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto" "STAGEtrain_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGEtrain_TFLAGS=" "STAGEfeedback_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fprofile-use -fprofile-reproducible=parallel-runs" "STAGEfeedback_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fprofile-use -fprofile-reproducible=parallel-runs" "STAGEfeedback_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGEfeedback_TFLAGS=" "STAGEautoprofile_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fno-checking -gtoggle -g" "STAGEautoprofile_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fno-checking -gtoggle -g" "STAGEautoprofile_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGEautoprofile_TFLAGS=-fno-checking" "STAGEautofeedback_CFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fchecking=1" "STAGEautofeedback_CXXFLAGS=-march=native -O3 -flto=auto -fchecking=1" "STAGEautofeedback_GENERATOR_CFLAGS=" "STAGEautofeedback_TFLAGS=-fchecking=1" "CXX_FOR_TARGET= $r/./gcc/xg++ -B$r/./gcc/ -nostdinc++ if test -f $r/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/scripts/testsuite_flags; then /bin/sh $r/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/scripts/testsuite_flags --build-includes; else echo -funconfigured-libstdc++-v3 ; fi -L$r/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src -L$r/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L$r/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs" "TFLAGS=" "CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh" "MAKEINFO=makeinfo --split-size=5000000 --split-size=5000000"  compare

make[2]: Entering directory '/home/urquelle/git/build'\
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/urquelle/git/build'\
rm -f stage_current\
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/urquelle/git/build'\
Comparing stages 2 and 3\
Bootstrap comparison failure!\
gcc/insn-emit.o differs\
make[2]: *** [Makefile:27165: compare] Error 1\
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/urquelle/git/build'\
make[1]: *** [Makefile:27145: stage3-bubble] Error 2\
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/urquelle/git/build'\
make: *** [Makefile:1072: all] Error 2
```

I was expecting both stages to be exactly the same, binary wise. I haven't really tried much as I wouldn't know where to begin. I would very appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

UPDATE 1:

After further investigation I found out, the differences in object sizes can be explained (at least partially) by the inclusion of debug information in stage-2, according to: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html, as make defaults to bootstrap-debug.

However, the instruction also claims (and this is further confirmed in the output I included) resulting objects will have their debug symbols stripped during the comparison. Furthermore, I explicitly tested building with manually added -g switch to BOOT_CFLAGS, only to get the result I had before (comparison fail on insn-emit.o).

UPDATE 2:

I've tried building with other flag permutations, and came to the conclusion it is the -flto switch that makes the build fail. I still have no idea why would it, since according to the manual it is a legitimate way of building GCC.

SOLUTION:

I managed to solve the problem myself. Apparently some of the default comparison checks are broken on default bootstrap-debug config. The solution is to explicitly configure with --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto. Contrary to what the manual says, this is not simply equivalent to adding -flto to BOOT_CFLAGS, but also removes few comparison checks in the resulting makefile. Hope this helps anyone who stumbles on this problem in the future.

Comment: `-flto` will include GIMPLE section in the `.o` files as well as machine code, so the optimizer can re-optimize across .o files.  If you're not using `-flto` for both stage 2 and stage 3 builds, you should expect very different results.  I'm not familiar enough with GCC build details to know if that `make` command should have applied to both stage 2 and stage 3 builds, but from the 2x size I'd guess not.

Comment: Thanks for reply @PeterCordes, interesting remark, I think it would be really odd for stage-2 not having applied -flto as well, since according to "https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html" bootstrap-lto is a valid way of building GCC and is equivalent to adding -flto to CFLAGS. I believe this manual also specifies stages-2 and 3 being compiled with exactly the same flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself. Apparently some of the default comparison checks are broken on default bootstrap-debug config. The solution is to explicitly configure with --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto. Contrary to what the manual says, this is not simply equivalent to adding -flto to BOOT_CFLAGS, but also removes few comparison checks in the resulting makefile. Hope this helps anyone who stumbles on this problem in the future.